# find column max and column average by using python programming

Tags: python, list, max, average

I have done the hard code for the following program, but i m not able how to find its average and it max from each column.

the output should look something like this:

```
2.42  11.42  13.86  72.32
56.59  88.52  4.33  87.70
73.72 50.50 7.97 84.47
============================
73.72 88.52 13.86 87.70  column max
44.24 50.15 8.72 81.50   column average
```

I have some what done this

```
list1=[2.42, 11.42,13.86,72.32]
list2=[56.59,88.52,4.33,87.70]
list3=[73.72,50.50,7.97,84.47]
data=[]
print   list1
print   list2
print   list3

print "=========================="
```

output

```
================================
[2.42, 11.42, 13.86, 72.32]
[56.59, 88.52, 4.33, 87.7]
[73.72, 50.5, 7.97, 84.47]
==========================
```

Comment: Have you tried to find the max or the average?

Comment: Pro tip: a list can contain *other* lists. Instead of creating three list variables, use *one* variable with a list containing 3 nested lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use something like this

```
list1=[2.42, 11.42,13.86,72.32]
list2=[56.59,88.52,4.33,87.70]
list3=[73.72,50.50,7.97,84.47]

print("============================")
print(list1)
print(list2)
print(list3)
print("============================")

for i in range(len(list1)):
    data = []
    data.append(list1[i])
    data.append(list2[i])
    data.append(list3[i])
    print(str(max(data)).rjust(i+1),end = " ")

print("\n")

for i in range(len(list1)):
    summ = list1[i] + list2[i] + list3[i]
    avr = summ / 3
    print(str(avr).rjust(i+1),end= " ")
```

You may want to use list of list for more efficient data.
By using list of list you can avoid that hard coded 3 when counting average.

Comment: "but how do you print the max in one line and average in one line "

Comment: By using .rjust() function.[python : Input output](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) check this official tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
list1=[2.42, 11.42,13.86,72.32]
list2=[56.59,88.52,4.33,87.70]
list3=[73.72,50.50,7.97,84.47]

maxs = [max(col) for col in zip(list1, list2, list3)]
means = [sum(col)/len(col) for col in zip(list1, list2, list3)]

print list1
print list2
print list3
print maxs
print means
```

Comment: And then explain to the teacher exactly how that clever code (that you *really* wrote yourself!) works. :-)